# Smooth out a raster in QGIS 3.30

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am making a topographical map with the help of DEM rasters in QGIS, however I stumbled upon a problem I can't find a solution to. As the DEM has a lot of water topographical data (DEM is from a coastal area and ocean adjacent to it), and I had to cut it off. The result is a rather choppy looking coastal area. While the solution in the previous version would have been SAGA Gaussian Filter, in this version it doesn't seem to be available anymore.

[image: Example of the choppiness of cut of coastal area.]

Comment: SAGA tools are still available if you install the Saga NextGen Processing Provider plugin (just search for SAGA in the plugin manager).  However, your question is a little unclear. Can you edit it to define what you mean by "choppy".  It looks fine to me, given the resolution of the DEM. If you want a smoother transition between data -> no data areas, you could increase the resolution of the DEM before clipping it.